# Is it possible to sync real-time 2 Database on 1 SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, mirroring, log-shipping

I want to clone my Database1 to Database2 and sync it in real-time, just like mirroring but only using 1 SQL Server Instance

I tried Log Shipping and Mirroring but it's not possible to use only 1 SQL Server Instance

Comment: Why? Why not read from the other database directly? What are you trying to do? `not possible using only 1 SQL Server Instance` because it makes no sense - the data is already there, it doesn't need to move anywhere else.

Comment: Besides, mirroring isn't the only way to copy data and you already used the `log-shipping` tag.  You *can* set up replication between local databases. Why would you want to do that though? It matters

Comment: I think you can logship to same server, even if it's kinda weird. Btw, nice user name

Comment: Are you trying to create a read-only replica to avoid blocking? A far better option is to use snapshot isolation or a proper reporting database. Querying the wrong schema is still querying the wrong schema and just as slow. Having proper indexes or columnstore indexes will improve performance immensely without having to duplicate the data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos nice catch! that's what I was exactly trying to solve.

Comment: Then you're using the wrong solution. You still haven't described the problem though. Making a read-only copy is the dirty way of fixing concurrency or schema issues. Are you trying to reduce blocking between updates? Speed up reporting? If a query scans and locks an entire table, *removing* the need for a full scan will solve problems. That may mean adding any missing indexes.

Comment: the updates queries are taking too long to finish and it's affecting the reporting functionality of the application because of table locking resulting in blocking the select queries of the reports, It's not a resources problem we haven't peak the server resources yet

Comment: That's a bad design then, and a worse fix. Real-time updating of a reporting replica will still lock the replicated tables. It's a bad idea to use the same tables for OLTP and reporting in the first place. If you really have to, you can use a [database snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-snapshots-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) for reporting. No log shipping is needed. Using proper indexes will remove the need to scan entire tables though.